# 1st order question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This equation for a house heating - in particular case can be written with time in hours

$c\cdot\dfrac{d\big(Th\big)}{dt}=ku-\dfrac{(Th-T_0)}r$

$u$ represents the state of the system once its off $=0$ and once its on $=1$
and I have two unknown constants in this equation $c$ and $r$ 
my question is how can I solve two differential to find two unknown constants and that's by using mat lab .

Comment: any suggestions ??

Comment: sorry I made a mistake ... I was going to tag 1st order system but it turned out to be first order logic

Comment: what is $k$ does it depend on $t$?

Comment: k is the heating rate of the furnace k=90000BTU/hour

Comment: So can one assume that $c,k,u, T_0,r $ are constants?

Comment: c is the thermal capacity of the house k is the heating rate of the furnace Th is the temperature inside the house and its known also To is the temperature outside the house and r is the thermal resistance and its unknown

Answer (score 0):

NOTE:
I am assuming that $c,k,u, T_0,r $ are constants ie independent of $t$ for this solution, If they are not , my solution will be incorrect.

$c\cdot\dfrac{d\big(Th\big)}{dt}=ku-\dfrac{(Th-T_0)}r$

$\dfrac{d(Th)}{dt}  = \frac kc\cdot u - \frac{Th}r-\frac{T_0}r$

$\dfrac{d(Th)}{dt}+\frac{Th}r = \frac{ku}c-\frac{T_0}r$

Integrating factor = $e^{\int\frac 1r\,dt}=e^{\frac tr}$

$Th \cdot e^{\frac tr}=\displaystyle\int\bigg[\frac{ku}c-\frac{T_0}r\bigg]e^{\frac tr}\,dt $

$Th\cdot e^{\frac tr}=\bigg[\frac{ku}c-\frac{T_0}r\bigg]\displaystyle\int e^{\frac tr}\,dt$

$Th\cdot e^{\frac tr} =\bigg[\frac{ku}c-\frac{T_0}r\bigg]\cdot e^{\frac tr} \cdot\frac1{r}+C$

$Th = \bigg[\frac{ku}{rc}-\frac{T_0}{r^2}\bigg]+\frac{C}{e^{\frac tr}}$

Use values of $Th,k,c,u,T_0,r$ in the above to find $C$ and then you can plug in the known quantities to find the unknown.

Hope this is what you meant by the question.

Comment: thank u so much for your time and help ,,,,but i want to use mat lab solving this ,,,,any ideas???

Comment: @maryjo I think [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve-a-single-differential-equation.html#f1-7555) might help you